# Create database if not exists from DBAL level

Tags: doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm trying to create database like this:

```
const QUERY_DB_CREATE = "
    CREATE DATABASE :db_name
";
if (database is not exists) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(self::QUERY_DB_CREATE);
    $stmt->bindValue(':db_name', $db_name, 'string');

    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'testtesttest2'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect many things are wrong.  To start with, you can't use parameters for table and column names in prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [DoctrineBundle command](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand.php) (for use in the Symfony framework) for creating databases.  Without knowing more about your implementation details, these lines especially should be useful in your case:

```
    $tmpConnection = DriverManager::getConnection($params);
    ...
    $tmpConnection->getSchemaManager()->createDatabase($name);
```